# Hibernate Doesn't Flush Fast Enough to Catch DB Exceptions

Tags: java, database, hibernate, exception, transactions

I have a method, inside a Try/Catch block, which calls a Hibernate DB Save operation to insert a row.

The method completes successfully even though there are DB problems (e.g. when I insert a NULL into a non-NULL column). Then, at some later point, Hibernates attempts to "flush" or complete the transaction, and that's when errors get thrown.

This messes up the flow of my code because I depend on my method completing successfully to do other things, e.g. send out emails. After calling my method, I go on to send out emails based on the assumption that no errors have happened (otherwise I would have been thrown out of my code flow and into my Catch block, but this is **not** happening).

Does anyone have any ideas how to deal with this situation?

Comment: What kind of transaction management/strategy are you using? If you expect things to be commited to the DB, you should be using explicit transactions. It is never a good idea to rely on implicit transactions... http://hibernateprofiler.com/learn/alerts/DoNotUseImplicitTransactions

Comment: I am not sure, but is there a way to auto-flush immediately on the Hibernate layer? (I'm not talking about the DB layer, that one is still a transaction.)

Comment: Why aren't you getting an Exception?  Like a Hibernate or JDBC exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trivial answer is to simply call `Session.flush()` and any pending SQL will get run, causing any SQL exceptions that might be lurking to happen at that time.

On a sort of larger scope, you may want to look at options for validating your data at the application level, rather than relying on SQL exceptions to detect errors.  There are up and downsides to either way of course.

Comment: I would discourage the use of explicitly calling Session.flush(), the need to do this almost always indicates that you are using the Hibernate framework incorrectly. I do agree with your point about the application validating things for you. This can be done by expanding your hbm.xml mapping files to include the constraints which you have added to your DB. This has the bonus (good) side-effect of the hbm2ddl tool creating a closer-to-the-real-thing schema, if you use it.

Comment: So how do we know precisely when Hibernate flushes? If I don't use flush(), how do I know when to check for errors?

Comment: Generally it will flush before running a query (unless you change that config), before committing, and when flush() is called.  Other times are not guaranteed to you by the API.  Needing to explicitly flush() a a lot is indicative that your application design is "thinking about the database" when it should be "thinking about the application" and letting hibernate worry about the database.  Of course sometimes you're well beyond being able to do anything about that, and things just need to work.

Comment: Also note that if you're using spring to manage your transactions, when the final flush occurs depends on the defined transaction semantics for your call hierarchy.  In general, when spring decides to commit your transaction, hibernate will flush.

Comment: It is worth noting that there is a hibernate setting to configure it to flush on every command. The default is AUTO but it can be set to ALWAYS, which will usually come with a significant performance hit... http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html